# Comparing two strings from two different streams are never equal even though they should be

Tags: c#, stream, webrequest

I have a stream that is reading the response from a site. I am then saving that stream to text in a text file.

If I then run it again and compare the string from the same site and the text saved in the file it thinks they are different.

When I compare the two strings in a diff tool like WinMerge it find differences at apparently identical points.

What is happening? They are both using the default UTF8 encoder.

I appreciate this may be difficult to follow so I have written a working example for you.

Here is an example:

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var body = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var googReader = new StreamReader(body))
        using (var googFileStream = File.Open("goog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(googFileStream))
        {
            var googText = googReader.ReadToEnd();
            var fileText = fileReader.ReadToEnd();
            if (!string.Equals(googText, fileText))
            {
                googFileStream.Dispose();
                using (var msnWriter = new StreamWriter(File.Open("goog.txt", FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    msnWriter.Write(googText);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the apparent 'difference' as reported by WinMerge. It is apparently at the point between html; charset:
[image: Diff of the two strings]

Comment: Can you post an image of the entire highlighted text? It may be somewhere else. Without anything else to go on, I can tell you that even within a single encoding, there are a couple different codes that read as a single space; there's the basic "space" (decimal code 32) and the "non-breaking space" (code 255). Certain control codes like "unit separator" may also read as a space depending on the text renderer. If the codes are different, the strings are different, even though the appearance may be identical.

Comment: Can you view the two files in hex view to make sure there isn't a page invisible in there?

Comment: @KeithS The original is huge - it is the source from google's homepage. Remember the file is just a copy of what came from the site a couple of seconds previous. Is it likely that when saving the string it saved it in a way that would convert a space to non breaking space?

Comment: @BritishDeveloper - I would say it could be extremely likely, depending on what Google is sending you and how .NET would convert that from ASCII to UTF-8. There is a 1-1 conversion possible, but .NET may "simplify" the string so it can be displayed by less sophisticated text renderers.

Comment: For what it's worth, DiffMerge generally gives me better results than most of the other diff/merge tools out there.  When I ran your sample code and then compared the results, it highlighted the exact characters that were different between requests.  (Hint - it's further to the right than what WinMerge is showing here...)

Comment: sorry sorry - hold on. This may be a winmerge fail. As i take a closer look there's random guid and things coming in further along from the "conflict" so it is in fact a different result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems fine. It's just that `Google` actually returns different contents every time you send a request to it. Other than that you might try simplifying your code and use a site which doesn't return different contents everytime:

```
var file = "goog.txt";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
    if (!File.Exists(file) || !string.Equals(File.ReadAllText(file), data))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(file, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly right - one of the script blocks includes some kind of base-64-looking content that varies by every request.  So the streams *WILL NEVER* match between two distinct web requests, and should never be assumed to do so unless you fully control the source and render pipeline.

Comment: yep you are right. but cheers for the massively simpler code :)